# RestKit : mapping with nested object with no id (dupplicated)

Tags: ios, core-data, mapping, nested, restkit

I've difficulties mapping one particular case 
This is exactly the same issue as [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/95)

```
product:{
     "id": 123,
     "name": "Produce RestKit Sample Code",
     "description": "We need more sample code!",
     "tasks": [
         {"name": "Identify samples to write", "assigned_user_id":1},
         {"name": "Write the code", "assigned_user_id": 1},
         {"name": "Push to Github", "assigned_user_id": 1},
         {"name": "Update the mailing list", "assigned_user_id": 1}]
}
```

so I created mapping for a task object.
I created mapping for product object with relationship to a NSSET of tasks.

But now every time a parse new data, tasks are duplicated in core data. (normal cause no ID)

Tow solutions :

1. I can delete tasks of current product if new ones are found.
2. I can create an ID of task, using the product Id

I don't know how to implement any of this solutions. any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure how your mapping this task object, but I parse the `NSData` with the JSON string via:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                           options:0
                                                             error:&error];
```

In that case, I get a `NSDictionary` with one key, "product", and the object for that key is another dictionary. The object of that `NSDictionary` with a key of "tasks" is a `NSArray` of four `NSDictionary` objects.

Now, that JSON excerpt wasn't valid JSON, but I assume it was just a leaf of a broader JSON file. But for testing purposes, let's assume the JSON file was as follows:

```
{
    "product" : {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Produce RestKit Sample Code",
        "description": "We need more sample code!",
        "tasks": [
                  {"name": "Identify samples to write", "assigned_user_id": 1},
                  {"name": "Write the code", "assigned_user_id": 1},
                  {"name": "Push to Github", "assigned_user_id": 1},
                  {"name": "Update the mailing list", "assigned_user_id": 1}]
    }
}
```

Then I can parse that JSON like so:

```
NSString *filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"13628140" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                           options:0
                                                             error:&error];

NSDictionary *product = dictionary[@"product"];
NSArray *tasks = product[@"tasks"];
NSDictionary *firstTask = tasks[0];
NSString *firstName = firstTask[@"name"];
NSString *firstAssignedUserId = firstTask[@"assigned_user_id"];
```

or, alternatively, if you want to enumerate through the tasks:

```
NSDictionary *product = dictionary[@"product"];
NSArray *tasks = product[@"tasks"];

[tasks enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDictionary *task = obj;
    NSLog(@"Task \"%@\" is assigned to %@", task[@"name"], task[@"assigned_user_id"]);
}];
```

Are you just asking how to store that `NSArray` of `tasks` in Core Data?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I managed to parse "tasks" but the issue is stocking them into Coredata without creating duplicated tasks.
For now I intercept the "willMapData" delegate of object loader and delete all "tasks" of the parsed "product" before adding new ones. It works, but it's not as clean as I'd like it to be.